# PNG Image of my UIImageView doesn't not appear, but another PNG image appears

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage, ios7

Yes it is very strange.

It as nothing special. From Interface Builder, i select it as Image, then the image appears in nib in xcode. But when i run it on my device, the image does not appear. If i select "yellow" as background of my UIImageView, the yellow backround appears instead of the image.

And if i select another picture as "image" of the UIImageView, it works. All are PNG format.

Everytime i run the app on the device, i do a "clean" before i build.

Here is the picture which doesn't work.

[image]

Any idea ?

So wierd ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK i found the solution.

Right click on the image in Xcode, go to File Inspector, i had to check the checkbox under "Target Membership"

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer, probably saved me hours.

Comment: Thank you for this, you just saved me from bashing my head against the wall. My drywall thanks you also.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have just added a reference to that image and not added it to the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

something similar happened to me, what i did was closed xcode,  change the folder name of the project, open it again and build, and worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Xcode 5 the other day – my solution was to remove the image files from the project completely, close Xcode, then re-add them. You could also use Asset Catalogs and it should fix the issue.